# how to find growth rate

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

How to find growth rate of below expression
a) $(2/3)^n + (\sum_{i=1}^n) \sin^2n +n^2 +\ln((\sum_{i=1}^n) nCi)$
b)$ nC2 + \sum_{i=1}^n \log n + n^2 \sin n$

I don't understand how to get the growth rate of the above expressions

Comment: Please use [$\text{MathJax}$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Do you mean $C_i$ and $C_2$?  If so, `$C_i$` comes out as $C_i$.  If not, what do $Ci$ and $C2$ mean?